# Keras/Tensorflow CNN input shape

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, convolution

I have a textfile that is ~ 10k lines long. There are always 216 lines describe a fact with a total of 17 values. I want to build a tensor that is 216 lines high, 13 columns wide and about 1000 layers deep. That would be the input.

The output would be one line high, 4 columns wide and also about 1000 layers deep.

Current status:

```
x_train = x_train.reshape (1308, 13, 216)
y_train = y_train.reshape (1308, 4, 216)
result = y_train [:,:, 0]
```

Conv:

```
model.add (Convolution2D (1, kernel_size = (13, 5), activation = 'relu', input_shape = (1308, 13, 216)))
```

Afterwards little maxpooling, etc., which should not disturb. I absolutely do not get along with the reshapes rightly. Would be very bad if someone could help me.

Current error message:

> Input arrays should have the same number of samples as target arrays.
>   Found 1 input samples and 1308 target samples.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I needed to change it into

```
input_shape = (13, 216, 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think changing from `input_shape = (1308, 13, 216)` to `input_shape = (13, 216)` should work.